# Reverse custom function PHP from experience to level

Tags: php, pow

I have a function where i input a level, and it returns the XP:

this is gotten from runescape 1-99 formula:

```
 function experience($L) {
      $a=0;
      for($x=1; $x<$L; $x++) {
        $a += floor($x+300*pow(2, ($x/7)));
      }
      return floor($a/4);
    }
```

this means:

```
 level 54 would return 150872 XP.
```

But, how would i go the other way around, to input 150872 and make it return 54?
and, whats the way to go when xp might be 150873, but its still level 54 to return?

How would i approatch?

Wants:

```
experience(152439) -> 54
```

Answer (score 2):

One inefficient but easy solution is to just continuously call the experience function in a loop, increasing the level each time, until you reach a level that returns an experience value above the one you are looking for, and then return the level before that:

```
function level($experience) {
    $returned = 0;
    $level = 0;

    while ($returned <= $experience) {
        $level++;
        $returned = experience($level);
    }

    return $level - 1;
}
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/820d659feb28a00dd87a21d01bd2414cbc66d300